# How to Solve this error message on Abaqus 'time increment required is less than specified' and 'too many attempts made for this increment'?

Tags: structural-engineering, finite-element-method, abaqus

I am currently working on my dissertation project using abaqus, my model is an arch bridge consisting of a shell and solid elements, there are concrete and steel materials also, I have checked all of the constraints, and I found that there are some constraints giving the error messages 'time increment required is less than specified' and 'too many attempts made for this increment', specifically, those constraints happened in shell-solid tie constraints. the other constraints between solid to solid were fine.

Can anybody help me resolve these problems?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. in my case, it was a mistake of a non-uniform unit in abaqus. so I strongly recommend to check the uniformity of your unit and boundary condition, the insufficient boundary condition can lead this error to occur

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can try is to go into the step manager and change the minimum increment size and maximum number of increments.   However as this appears to be on the very first increment there is likely something wrong with the model such as inconsistent boundary conditions.

Looking at the `.msg` file is usually enlightening.

Comment: thank you very much, it is very helpful for me.. this problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the iteration count in each step. You can follow this video to solve this issue.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ09lt8yRtc&t=2s